Is it possible to include algebraic states in DaeBuilder instance when importing dynamics from an FMU?
I'm using CasADi's DaeBuilder to import FMUs created in Dymola to Python (FMU 2.0 Model Exchange). As of now, any algebraic state is included in the dynamics but is not visible in the DaeBuilder instance. Would this be possible to include or is it a consequence of how the FMU is generated?
This is a simple "nonsense" Modelica-code used to demonstrate:
model dae_test

  parameter Real a = 3;
  Real x(start=0.3);
  Real z;

  input Real u(start=0.1);
  output Real y;

equation 

  der(x)= a*z + u;
  z = 0.1*x;
  y = z;

end dae_test;

**
In Python:**
dae = ca.DaeBuilder('dae', unzipped_path)

print(dae) yields: nx = 1, nz = 0, nq = 0, ny = 1, np = 1, nc = 0, nd = 0, nw = 0, nu = 1
The algebraic state z is not visible, but the resulting system is integrated correctly with 'cvodes' (and 'idas') using:
f = dae.create('f')
sim = ca.integrator('sim', 'cvodes', f, 0, tgrid)
r = sim(x0 = x0, u = u0, p=3)

Implementing the same directly in Python (without outputs):
dae=ca.DaeBuilder('dae')

x=dae.add_x('x')
a=dae.add_p('a')
u=dae.add_u('u')
z=dae.add_z('z')

xdot = z*a + u
zval = 0.1*x

dae.set_ode('x', xdot)
dae.set_alg('z', zval)

print(dae) yields: nx = 1, nz = 1, nq = 0, ny = 0, np = 1, nc = 0, nd = 0, nw = 0, nu = 1
Although now, integrating this instance using 'idas' gives error... (This is probably solvable, but as of now my main interest is in the algebraic state import)
f = dae.create('f')

tgrid = np.linspace(0., T, 100) 
sim = ca.integrator('sim', 'idas', f, 0, tgrid)
r = sim(x0 = 0.3, u = 0.1, p=3, z0=0.1*0.3)

I'm new to CasADi and FMUs, so maybe this has a simple explanation, but any thoughts would be appreciated!
I've searched for examples in CasADi's example pack, but I can't seem to find similar problems. I know the implementation of FMU import was added in CasADi 3.6 last fall, and examples are limited.
